# R script question - is.na telling me the condition has length > 1

Tags: r, nls

In my r script, I do perform an nls to get a fit value:

```
fit <- nls(...)
```

and then after that, I test if the nls succeeded by doing this:

```
if(is.na(fit)) {
  print("succeeded")
}
```

but I get warnings:

```
the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

am I doing this wrong? if so, what should I do? if not, how do I remove the warning? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nls` induces an error if the fitting failed. So, `is.null` after `try(nls(...))` is the correct way.

here is a piece of code I used when using `nls` fit for uncertain data:

```
fit <- NULL
while (TRUE) {
    start <- list(...) # try somewhat randomized initial parameter
    try(fit <- nls(..., start = start)) # performe nls
    if (!is.null(fit)) break;
}
```

Comment: I think `fit <- try(nls(...); if (!inherits(fit,"try-error")) break` is a more standard idiom ... ? Also, you can use `repeat` instead of `while (TRUE)` ...